# Chevrolet 6L90 transmission interchange

Tags: chevrolet, transmission

Are 6L90 transmissions interchangable between the different types of vehicles that GM puts them in? Example: Camaro and Silverado 2500HD

Comment: There may be interchange between the 2WD truck version and the Camaro version, but the case is physically different when you look at the 4WD truck version. Also, [there are only two cars](http://gmauthority.com/blog/gm/gm-transmissions/myd/) which use the 6L90: Camaro ZL1; Cadillac CTS-V. Every other application is in a truck/van of some sort. You won't just find them laying around out of a car is what I'm getting at.

Comment: @Paulster2 : Any reason why this is a comment and not an answer?

Answer (score 2):

There may be interchange between the 2WD truck version and the Camaro version, but the case is physically different when you look at the 4WD truck version. Also, [there are only two cars](http://gmauthority.com/blog/gm/gm-transmissions/myd/) which use the 6L90: Camaro ZL1; Cadillac CTS-V. Every other application is in a truck/van of some sort. You won't just find them laying around out of a car is what I'm getting at.

[image]